# How to simulate AWS Lambda retryable error response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function with Image package type, and it executes rarely. During the invoke, lambda responses `CodeArtifactUserPendingException`. And saying the function will be ready shorty. The error also has `retryale` property. From the next invoke, I couldn't reproduce this error. Is there any way to simulate the same response from Lambda with `retryale` property?

[image]

I have tried below in the new lambda function to get the same response.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return {
        StatusCode: 500,
        code: 'CodeArtifactUserPendingException',
        retryale: true,
        name: 'CodeArtifactUserPendingException'
    }
};
```

and

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    throw new Error({
        StatusCode: 500,
        code: 'CodeArtifactUserPendingException',
        retryale: true,
        name: 'CodeArtifactUserPendingException'
    });
};
```

But on both case, the `error` parameter in the callback has `null` value and the data has below

```
{
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST",
  "Payload": "{\"StatusCode\":500,\"code\":\"CodeArtifactUserPendingException\",\"retryale\":true,\"name\":\"CodeArtifactUserPendingException\"}"
}
```

Am I approaching correctly? Or direct me to the right path.

Comment: shouldn't it be retryable: true?

Comment: @AreUMinee No, retryable:true isn't work